# How to download and install Boost

Tags: windows, boost, cmake, qt-creator

On Windows, I'm trying to work on a CMake project which requires Boost. CMake cannot find Boost. How can I ***install Boost***?

I'm reading [this getting started guide](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) and other guides, but it is *not* clear for me.

I'm trying to open the CMake project with Qt Creator:

> > Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR system filesystem thread
> > log locale regex chrono atomic date_time)

[image: Error message]

---

#### Update

Downloaded `boost_1_73_0.7z` file, unpacked it and moved it to

```
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_73_0
```

Added environment variable `BOOST_ROOT` set to `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_73_0`.

Now the error message is changed to:

> > Could NOT find Boost (missing: system filesystem thread log locale regex
> > chrono atomic date_time) (found version "1.73.0")

[image: Error message after unpacking]

Comment: Add `Boost_DEBUG=ON` option for `cmake` and configure the project again. That time CMake will print all paths which are searched. Compare these paths with what you actually have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the error got resolved by installing the boost with [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg):

```sh
C:\Users\m3\repos\vcpkg>.\vcpkg.exe install boost:x64-windows
```

Also had to add this CMake option:

```
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Users/m3/repos/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

I switched to JetBrains IDE, so had to add CMake options here:

[image: IdE CMake options]